# How to fix: Message: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: chrome not reachable

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, jenkins

I'm setting up Selenium based regression tests using ChromeDriver on a Jenkins ECS slave.

ChromeDriver is installedn on the ECS slave using Maven-plugin `"driver-binary-downloader-maven-plugin"`

When logging in the docker container I see ChromeDriver installed in 
`/usr/bin/linux/googlechrome/64bit/chromedriver`

Docker container is started with `--privileged`

---

**pom.xml**

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.lazerycode.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>driver-binary-downloader-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.17</version>
    <configuration>
        <rootStandaloneServerDirectory>/usr/bin</rootStandaloneServerDirectory>
        <downloadedZipFileDirectory>drivers/zips</downloadedZipFileDirectory>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>selenium</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

**BrowserDriverHolder.java**

```java
private WebDriver createDriver(final String driverName, final String headless) {
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    if (headless.toLowerCase().equals("true")) {
      options.addArguments("headless");
    }

    options.addArguments("debug");
    options.addArguments("no-sandbox");

    options.setBinary("/usr/bin/linux/googlechrome/64bit/chromedriver");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/usr/bin/linux/googlechrome/64bit/chromedriver");
    options.addArguments("window-size=1920,1080");
    ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(360, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(360, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    return driver;
}
```

---

ECS container comes up successfully and starts regression testing, getting this error message:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.33.506092 (733a02544d189eeb751fe0d7ddca79a0ee28cce4) on port 19809
Only local connections are allowed.
Starting ChromeDriver 2.33.506092 (733a02544d189eeb751fe0d7ddca79a0ee28cce4) on port 9515
Only local connections are allowed.
Message: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: chrome not reachable
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506092 (733a02544d189eeb751fe0d7ddca79a0ee28cce4),platform=Linux 4.14.77-69.57.amzn1.x86_64 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 60.17 seconds
Build info: version: '3.8.1', revision: '6e95a6684b', time: '2017-12-01T18:33:54.468Z'
System info: host: 'ip-172-27-93-92.eu-central-1.compute.internal', ip: '172.27.93.92', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.14.77-69.57.amzn1.x86_64', java.version: '9.0.4'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:488)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:214)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:166)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonWireProtocolResponse.lambda$new$0(JsonWireProtocolResponse.java:53)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonWireProtocolResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$2(JsonWireProtocolResponse.java:91)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:123)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:127)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:502)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:488)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:152)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:476)
```

ChromeDriver is running and listening on the given ports.

I'm struggling to find the solution, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably there is a mismatch between chromedriver version and Google Chrome binary on your machine.

1. Your Maven plugin seems to be downloading [Chromedriver version 2.33](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.33/)
2. Looking into [Chromedriver 2.33 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.33/notes.txt)

   > Supports Chrome v60-62

So you either need to ramp-up the chromedriver version or downgrade your Chrome to be between 60 and 62 inclusively.

I also believe the options must be prefixed with 2 dashes like:

```
options.addArguments("--headless")
```

If downgrading browser or upgrading driver isn't something you can afford - consider using [remote testing in Selenium cloud](https://experitest.com/real-desktop-mobile-browsers/), as of now Chrome versions from 43 to 67 are supported and it includes 60-62 sub-range.